Message even after updating targetsdk etc (This app was built for an older version of Android...)
Problem: I am getting the following when trying to run/install my MAUI Android app:
Unable to Install: This app was built for an older version of Android and doesn't include the latest privacy protections

What I tried: I updated both the properties of the .csproj file, as well as the AndroidManifest.xml file.
I tried nuget package restore on the solution. I did a clean and rebuild.
What else do I need to do to resolve this?
Properties/AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.arc.myapp.p" android:versionName="185.06.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/myapp_icon_180px" android:supportsRtl="true">  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
                 android:theme="@style/ETheme">

Myapp.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android34.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!--<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>-->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MyApp</ApplicationTitle>
        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.myapp</ApplicationId>
        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>


What device are you trying to install this on?

Ive gotten this on multiple devices: Samsung Galaxy S20FE, Google Pixel 6 Pro

Do they have the same API level?

S20 is on Android 13. Pixel is on Android 14.

Also happens on Samsung S9 on Android 10

I am also experiencing this across several devices

Because of the new Target API requirements apps that were not at a certain api level got blocked for some system. In some cases,this shouldn't have happened, but it is an issue that cause a problem for a few apps that had in production very old SDKs.
For more information, you can check: Target API level requirements for Google Play apps.

But mine is set to 34, so the error doesnt make sense. Also this is when installing the apk doing a run from Visual Studio. This is not actually from the store.

Also, it has no problem running on emulators. But it doesnt work on any device.

How can we reproduce this problem on my side? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Have you tried to use net8.0-android instead of net8.0-android34.0?

@JessieZhang-MSFT i have tried net8.0-android and still get the same issue
